# Close modal popup on click of button inside the modal

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I have a usercontrol which is being displayed in a modal popup.

```
<ajt:ModalPopupExtender OkControlID="btnOk" runat="server"
                PopupControlID="pnlViewOrderItems" ID="mpxViewItems" TargetControlID="btnOk"
                BehaviorID="bhvIDViewProd" CancelControlID="ImgbtnCloseViewItems" />
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlViewOrderItems" runat="server" Style="display: none; padding: 0px;
                margin: 0px;" CssClass="mdlPopUp">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgbtnCloseViewItems" Style="position: absolute; top: -15px;
                    right: -25px;" ImageUrl="~/Images/site/close.gif" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
                <div id="divOrderItems" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" style="overflow: auto;
                    padding: 0px">
                    <table cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr style="height: 5px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" class="mdlHdr" valign="top">
                            <td align="center" colspan="2">
                                <h3>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblMdlHrd" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </h3>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 20px; width: 100%" colspan="2">
                                <uc:CustomerOrderDetails ID="ucCustOrderDetails" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
```

The user enters some data and clicks a button, clicking which I want to close the modal popup.

```
protected void btnCloseModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Some code.
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "CloseModal", "CloseModal();", true);
}
function CloseModal() {
            debugger;
            $find('bhvIDViewProd').hide();
        }
```

But its not closing the modal popup. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: remove `debugger` inside `CloseModal` function

Answer (score 0):

You can directly associate a JS function for the `OnCancelScript` for the `ModalPopupExtender` and from there you can close the modal popup like below. You don't need to post to code behind and trigger the JS function.

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender .... CancelControlID="ButtonCancel" OnCancelScript="CancelScript();"
</asp:ModalPopupExtender>
```

And you JavaScript function

```
function CancelScript() {
     $find('bhvIDViewProd').hide();
}
```